# How to write rules to match two arrays?

Tags: java, drools

I am new to drools so some help would be greatly appreciated. I have two json files that I have to apply some rules to. I have converted both the json to java class and inserted the classes into the rules engine.

I have to write a rule which checks an array which is present in both the json files is equal or not. InputFile and OutputFile are the class for the two json respectively.

Suppose array in the first json contains [6,4,8] and array in the second json also contains [6,4,8] then the rule that I have written to check if both the array are equal is

```
rule "EqualArray"
when
    $arrInInput : InputFile($inputArr : inputArray)
    $arrInOutput : OutputFile($outputArr : outputArray == $inputArr)
then
    System.out.println($inputArr+" and "+$outputArr+" Rule passed");
end
```

The output of the code is

```
6 and 6 Rule passed
4 and 4 Rule passed
8 and 8 Rule passed
```

The rule that I have written to check if both the array are not equal is

```
rule "Not EqualArray"
when
    $arrInInput : InputFile($inputArr : inputArray)
    $arrInOutput : OutputFile($outputArr : outputArray != $inputArr)
then
    System.out.println($inputArr+" and "+$outputArr+" Rule failed");
end
```

The output of this rule is

```
6 and 4 Rule failed
6 and 8 Rule failed
4 and 6 Rule failed
4 and 8 Rule failed
8 and 6 Rule failed
8 and 4 Rule failed
```

As both the array are equal I don't want the "Not EqualArray" rule to fire. 
What I want is to write rules so that I can check the array values by the index. For example if index 1, index 2 and index 3 of both the arrays match, the array is equal and if the value of both the array don't match for a particular index then the rule "Not EqualArray" to fire. I also don't have control on the size of the array. The json can have any number of values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Procedural algorithms are easier to implement in a procedural language. I would suggest you to implement the logic in Java (either in a class or as a function in the DRL) and to invoke that logic from the LHS of your rules.

Comment: Could you help me with an example. I don't understand how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: No. I haven't written the comparison code in Java because I have been trying compare the array list in Drools. I have changed the data structure from array to a list as it might be a bit easier handling lists.